# Passing an object as a buffer in irecv - TypeError: expected a writeable buffer object

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I'm using MPI for a project. I need to transmit a package from a node to another in non-blocking mode. I'm organizing this package with a Class that contains relevant information for my communication logic.

I'm making some tests with the functions `irecv()` to get the request of my communication and the buffer and also `test()` to verify if some message arrived.

MPI lacks of documentation for Python, so I'm inspecting the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/src/master/src/mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx) for more information, where is the functions i'm using.

The source code declares irecv as following:

```py
def irecv(self, buf=None, int source=ANY_SOURCE, int tag=ANY_TAG):
        """Nonblocking receive"""
        cdef MPI_Comm comm = self.ob_mpi
        cdef Request request = <Request>Request.__new__(Request)
        request.ob_buf = PyMPI_irecv(buf, source, tag, comm, &request.ob_mpi)
        return request
```

I understood that if I want the data to be put in a buffer I need to set the optional parameter "buf" with where I want my received message to be stored.

I tried the following test to learn how It works:

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
import time

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

class Package(object):
    msg = [[0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1]]

    gotMessage = False

    destination = -1

if rank == 0:
    data = Package()
    comm.isend(data, dest=1, tag=11)
elif rank == 1:
    data = Package()
    req = comm.irecv(buf=data, source=0, tag=11)
    while not req.test():
        sleep(0.1)
    print(rank, data.msg)
```

I was expecting the following behaviour:

1. Node with rank 0 send the packet as an object to node with rank 1
2. Node with rank 1 starts receiving non-blockingly and, when it finishes the receiving, what happens when `test()` returns `True`, I can print the `data.msg`.

The problem is, when I run the following error occurs at `buf`:

TypeError: expected a writeable buffer object

How can I correctly use `irecv()` to transmit/receive objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mpi4py`, there are two kinds of interfaces on top of MPI. A low-level interface that communicates buffers back and forth (indicated by a capital letter, i.e. `Isend`), and a high-level interface that communicates python objects (i.e. `isend`).

The high-level interface serializes objects via pickle. For non-blocking operations  this needs a buffer that is user-supplied and needs to be large enough. The `test` function on the other hand returns a `found, object` tuple. So using the high-level interface, your code receiver looks like:

```
buf = bytearray(b" " * 256)
req = comm.irecv(buf=buf, source=0, tag=11)
while True:
    found, data = req.test()
    if found:
        break
    time.sleep(0.1)
print(1, data.msg)
```

Note, your sender code is missing the completion of the message. But it should not matter whether you `send` or `isend` the data.

In any case, you have to somehow determine a sufficient buffer size for the receive buffer, which is probably impossible to do really cleanly. If the buffer is too small, you will receive an `MPI.Exception`.

You can also use the low-level interface. For instance, you can send around numpy arrays easily:

```
if rank == 0:
    data = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=float)
    comm.Send(data, dest=1, tag=11)
elif rank == 1:
    data = np.zeros(3, dtype=float)
    req = comm.Irecv(buf=data, source=0, tag=11)
    while True:
        found = req.Test()
        if found:
            break
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print(1, data)
```

The `shape` and `dtype` must match to make sense of it.